# Naudio playback in memory samples produces delays and unaesthetic gaps in the sound

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, waveout

Using  **`BufferedWaveProvider`** for playback of audio samples which are stored in database as `double[]`

```
 _bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(Format)
                                {
                                    DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true,
                                    BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                                };

public void Consume(double[] samples, int offset, int count)
{
   samples.Paginate<double, float>(offset, count)
          .ForEach(x =>
          {
            byte[] consumeBuffer = x.ToBytes(ref _consumeBuffer);

            _bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(consumeBuffer, 0, _consumeBuffer.Length);
           });
}
```

The audio when played back is producing gaps in sound. Samples are sent inside `Consume()` method for every 100ms. Is there a problem that the `WaveOut()` is playing faster than we call `Consume()` method ? How do we synchronize this reading and playback.

Comment: the waveOut API uses a pull model by default. You and/or NAudio have turned it somehow into a push model so, yes, it is possible that your not calling `Consume` fast enough. Another possibility is that you're calling it to fast and the buffer is being dropped (`DiscardOnBufferOverflow`). You haven't shown how it is called though so it's not possible to provide a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

A better choice here would be `RawSourceWaveStream` rather than `BufferedWaveProvider`, which would allow you to play directly from a `MemoryStream` containing the full audio.

Comment: I use BufferedWaveProvider to perform, Pause() and Resume(), Mixing multiple channels, Equalizing. Don't know how to achieve these using MemoryStream. Can we initialize WaveOut first and then add data to MemoryStream ? it din't work. Moreover, I'm plotting the waveform while playing it, It was easier to use BufferedWaveProvider.

Comment: I assumed that since your data is in a database, then you actually have access to the whole audio data up front.